# Regex for alphanumeric string

Tags: regex

Im trying to get a regex to find all the parts of this string seperated by pipe. My attempt thusfar finds the 233, but when i try to catch the alphanumeric string, it fails.

```
(\d+)?|([A-Z+0-9+])?
```

The string is

```
233|LTE02ERBS00126|N/A|ULSA|1|1|263655|/company/ul_spectrum_files/MeContext=LTE02ERBS00126,ManagedElement=1,1,1,20180305.123252ULSA_SAMPLE|1520253172|1520253172
```

Comment: Which language?

Comment: The vertical bar ("pipe") has a special meaning in regular expressions, namely specifying alternatives, so it will not match the actual vertical bar in your data. But I'm not sure which you want.

Comment: You can try `([^|]+|)+[^|]+` (https://regex101.com/r/g3wwel/3/), but it'll be better to use some version of `split` that should be available in your languager

Comment: Try [`\b(\d+|[A-Z0-9]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/U4PQmR/1). BTW, what is the expected result?

Comment: Regex doesn't seem like the best way this could be done, if you're in a language like Javascript you could use `String.split('|')`. However, here, have a regex: `/(?:\||^)[^|]+(?=\||$)/`

Comment: When you say "all the parts", how do you try to find all? The regexp itself matches only once.

Comment: People are thinking about the solution while OP has not clarified things yet.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ela about using negation This will catch everíthing until it hits a |

```
[^\|]+
```

Answer (score -2):

For this kind of match you should use a regexp with negation: you should match every character that is not a pipe.

I think you should use something like `[^\v]`

Comment: I'm not sure how suggesting a different separator would help answer this question? - What happens if they're trying to process a HL7 message from somewhere, the `|` is standard.